# Ajuda em um procedure com menor media de notas

Tags: mysql, sql

Crie uma procedure que liste a disciplina com a menor média de notas. Não consigo puxar e menor média e dei uma travada. Fiz esse código até o momento. Agradeço muito a ajuda dos amigos

```
DROP PROCEDURE if EXISTS pListaMenorMedia;
delimiter
CREATE PROCEDURE pListaMenorMedia
begin
select d.Nomesciplina, avg(N.nota) as mediaNota from Disciplina d
join Nota n on d.CodDisciplina = n.codDisciplina
where 
end;
$$
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Crie um subselect que liste todas as disciplinas com média de notas (AVG(Nota.nota) / GROUP BY Disciplina.codDisciplina) e um select que selecione a menor média e sua disciplina (MIN(média_das_notas)) a partir do subselect anterior.

Comment: foi o que eu estava pensando em fazer. Mas ainda tenho dúvidas de como fazer esse subselect. Vou continuar pesquisando, obrigado pela ajuda amigo

Comment: 1) se quier as médias por aluno precisa agrupar por aluno (`GROUP BY Nota.codAluno`)  2) se quer a menor média, precisa fazer o MIN (`MIN(AVG(Nota.nota)`)

Comment: Teste `SELECT foo.nomeDisciplina, MIN(foo.media) FROM (SELECT d.nomeDisciplina, AVG(n.nota) AS media FROM Disciplina d INNER JOIN Nota n ON (d.codDisciplina = n.codDisciplina) GROUP BY d.nomeDisciplina) foo`.